# On RDS can I create Tables in a Read Replica that are not present on the Master?

Tags: mysql, master-slave, rds

We have a separate RDS Instance to handle session state tables, however found that the session DB load is very low. if we can convert the instance handling session as a Read Replica of the main DB, then we can use it for read-only tasks that are safe even with a large lag in the copy.

Has anyone done something like this on RDS (Is it possible and safe)? Should I watch out for any serious side effects? Any links or help in understanding this better would help.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#95 attempts to answer the question but am looking for more insights.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. I am using it with success using `RDS`, for a specific case of local cache.

You need to set the `read_only` parameter on your replica to `0`. I've had to reboot my server in order for that parameter to work.

It's going to work nicely if use different table names, as RDS doesn't allow you to set: `replicate-ignore-table` parameter.

Remember there musn't be any data collision between master<>slave. If there is a statement which works ok on `MASTER`, but fails on `SLAVE`, then you've just broke your replication. That might happen e.g. when you've created table on `SLAVE` first then after some time you've added that table to `MASTER`. The `CREATE` statement will work clean on `MASTER`, but fail on `SLAVE`, as table already exist.

Assuming, you need to be really careful, allowing your application to write to `SLAVE`. If you forget / or make a mistake and start writing to read replica for some of your other data, in the end you might lose data or experience hard to debug issues.

Comment: I am getting an error when executing a delete operation because the user only has select permission on all tables. When I'm granting delete permission to the user in the read replica I'm getting the error: `Access denied for user...`
How to grant any permission in a read replica RDS instance?

Answer (score -1):

There's not a lot to add -- the only normal scenario that really makes sense on a pure read replica is things like adding a few indexes and the like if its used primarily for reporting or something else read-intensive.

If you're trying to pre-calculate a lot of data and otherwise modify what's on the read replica you need to be *really* careful you're not changing data -- if the read is no longer consistent then you're in trouble :)

If you're curious about what happens if you change data on the slave and the master tries to update it, you're already heading down the wrong path IMHO.

TL;DR Don't do it unless you *really* know what you're doing and you understand all the ramifications.

- And bluntly, MySQL replication can be quirky in my experience, so even knowing what is *supposed* to happen and what *does* happen if there's as the master tries to write updated data to slave you've also updated.... who knows.