# RDS Read Replica Considerations

Tags: mysql, database-replication, amazon-rds

We hired an intern and want to let him play around with our data to generate useful reports. Currently we just took a database snapshot and created a new RDS instance that we gave him access to. But that is out of date almost immediately due to changes on the production database.

What we'd like is a live (or close-to-live) mirror of our actual database that we can give him access to without worrying about him modifying any real data or accidentally bringing down our production database (eg by running a silly query like `SELECT (*) FROM ourbigtable` or a really slow join).

Would a read replica be suitable for this purpose? It looks like it would at least be staying up to date but I'm not clear what would happen if a read replica went down or if data was accidentally changed on it or any other potential liabilities.

The only thing I could find related to this [was this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405163/on-rds-can-i-create-tables-in-a-read-replica-that-are-not-present-on-the-master) and this has me a bit worried (emphasis mine):

> If you're trying to pre-calculate a lot of data and otherwise modify
>   what's on the read replica you need to be really careful you're not
>   changing data -- **if the read is no longer consistent then you're in
>   trouble** :)
>
> TL;DR Don't do it unless you really know what you're doing and you
>   understand all the ramifications.
>
> And bluntly, MySQL replication can be quirky in my experience, so even
>   knowing what is supposed to happen and what does happen **if there's as
>   the master tries to write updated data to slave you've also
>   updated.... who knows.**

Is there any risk to the production database if we let an intern have at it on an unreferenced read replica?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We've been running read-replicas of our production databases for a couple years now without any significant issues.  All of our sales, marketing, etc. people who need the ability to run queries are provided access to the replica. It's worked quite well and has been stable for the most part.  The production databases are locked down so that only our applications can connect to it, and the read-replicas are accessible only via SSL from our office.  Setting up the security is pretty important since you would be creating all the user accounts on the master database and they'd then get replicated to the read-replica.

I think we once saw a read-replica get into a bad state due to a hardware-related issue.  The great thing about read-replicas though is that you can simply terminate one and create a new one any time you want/need to.  As long as the new replica has the exact same instance name as the old one its DNS, etc. will remain unchanged, so aside from being briefly unavailable everything should be pretty much transparent to the end users.  Once or twice we've also simply rebooted a stuck read-replica and it was able to eventually catch up on its own as well.

There's no way that data on the read-replica can be updated by any method other than processing commands sent from the master database.  RDS simply won't allow you to run something like an insert, update, etc. on a read-replica no matter what permissions the user has.  So you don't need to worry about data changing on the read-replica causing things to get out of sync with the master.

Occasionally the replica can get a bit behind the production database if somebody submits a long running query, but it typically catches back up fairly quickly once the query completes.  In all our production environments we have a few monitors set up to keep an eye on replication and to also check for long running queries.  We make use of the [pmp-check-mysql-replication-delay](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-plugins/1.0/nagios/pmp-check-mysql-replication-delay.html) command in the [Percona Toolkit for MySQL](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit) to keep an eye on replication. It's run every few minutes via Nagios. We also have a custom script that's run via cron that checks for long running queries.  It basically parses the output of the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" command and sends out an e-mail if a query has been running for a long period of time along with the username of the person running it and the command to kill the query if we decide we need to.

With those checks in place we've had very little problem with the read-replicas.

Comment: Actually you can set read_only to 0 on the replica to allow write access if you want.

Comment: Here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-read-replica/ a link that shows how to set the read_only parameter to 0

Comment: Is there an automated way to promote read replica when master fails and similarly vice versa in case of disaster recovery. Also what are the ramifications if I use read replicas. I want the process to be automated .

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL replication works in a way that what happens on the slave has no effect on the master.

A replication slave asks for a history of events that happened on the master and applies them locally. The master never writes anything on the slaves: the slaves read from the master and do the writing themselves. If the slave fails to apply the events it read from the master, it will stop with an error.

The problematic part of this style of data replication is that if you modify the slave and later modify the master, you might have a different value on the slave than on the master. This can be avoided by turning on the global `read_only`variable.